# JavaScript - Limitar numero de páginas em paginação

Tags: javascript

Tenho um script onde mostro todas as páginas de uma tabela, por exemplo,

<< 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 >>

Entretanto, preciso limitar a exibição das páginas e não estou conseguindo. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

<< Inicio 1 2 3 4 5 Fim >>
<< Inicio 2 3 4 5 6 Fim >>

Segue o código já desenvolvido mostrando todas as páginas:

```
function Pager(tableName, itemsPerPage) {
    this.tableName = tableName;
    this.itemsPerPage = itemsPerPage;
    this.currentPage = 1;
    this.pages = 0;
    this.inited = false;

    this.showRecords = function(from, to) {        
        var rows = document.getElementById(tableName).rows;
        // i starts from 1 to skip table header row
        for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
            if (i < from || i > to)  
                rows[i].style.display = 'none';
            else
                rows[i].style.display = '';
        }
    }

    this.showPage = function(pageNumber) {
        if (! this.inited) {
            alert("not inited");
            return;
        }

        var oldPageAnchor = document.getElementById('pg'+this.currentPage);
        oldPageAnchor.className = 'pg-normal';

        this.currentPage = pageNumber;
        var newPageAnchor = document.getElementById('pg'+this.currentPage);
        newPageAnchor.className = 'pg-selected';

        var from = (pageNumber - 1) * itemsPerPage + 1;
        var to = from + itemsPerPage - 1;
        this.showRecords(from, to);
    }   

    this.prev = function() {
        if (this.currentPage > 1)
            this.showPage(this.currentPage - 1);
    }

    this.next = function() {
        if (this.currentPage < this.pages) {
            this.showPage(this.currentPage + 1);
        }
    }                        

    this.init = function() {
        var rows = document.getElementById(tableName).rows;
        var records = (rows.length - 1); 
        this.pages = Math.ceil(records / itemsPerPage);
        this.inited = true;
    }

    this.showPageNav = function(pagerName, positionId) {
        if (! this.inited) {
            alert("not inited");
            return;
        }
        var element = document.getElementById(positionId);
        var pagerHtml = getPagerHtml(pagerName, this.currentPage, this.pages);
        element.innerHTML = pagerHtml;
    }
}

function getPagerHtml(pagerName, currentPage, pages, maxPages) {
  maxPages = maxPages || 5; // default são 5 páginas
  var firstPage = parseInt(Math.max(currentPage - maxPages / 2, 1)); // Obtém a primeira página a ser exibida adicionando algumas páginas antes da atual, ou a primeira caso não tenha
  var lastPage = parseInt(firstPage + maxPages - 1); // Seleciona a última página a ser exibida
  // Caso ultrapasse a quantidade de páginas refazemos a seleção das páginas a serem exibidas
  if (lastPage > pages) {
    lastPage = pages;
    firstPage = lastPage - maxPages;
    if (firstPage < 1) {
      firstPage = 1;
    }
  }
  var pagerHtml = '<span onclick="' + pagerName + '.prev();" class="pg-ctrl"> &#171 </span>';
  for (var page = firstPage; page <= lastPage; page++) {
    pagerHtml += '<span id="pg' + page + '" class="pg-normal" onclick="' + pagerName + '.showPage(' + page + ');">' + page + '</span>';
  }
  pagerHtml += '<span onclick="'+pagerName+'.next();" class="pg-ctrl"> &#187;</span>';
  return pagerHtml;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiz umas alterações para o script funcionar. Você pode ignorar o fillTable por que é só para preencher a tabela com uns números.

```js
fillTable('table');
var pager = new Pager('table', 3, 'pager');
pager.init();
pager.showPage(1);

function Pager(tableName, itemsPerPage, pagerName) {
    this.tableName = tableName;
    this.itemsPerPage = itemsPerPage;
    this.pagerName = pagerName;
    this.maxPages = 5;
    this.currentPage = 1;
    this.pages = 0;
    this.inited = false;

    this.showRecords = function(from, to) {        
        var rows = document.getElementById(tableName).rows;
        // i starts from 1 to skip table header row
        for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
            if (i < from || i > to)  
                rows[i].style.display = 'none';
            else
                rows[i].style.display = '';
        }
    }

    this.showPage = function(pageNumber) {
        if (! this.inited) {
            alert("not inited");
            return;
        }

        this.showPageNav(pageNumber);

        var oldPageAnchor = document.getElementById('pg'+this.currentPage);
        if (oldPageAnchor) {
            oldPageAnchor.className = 'pg-normal';
        }

        this.currentPage = pageNumber;
        var newPageAnchor = document.getElementById('pg'+this.currentPage);
        newPageAnchor.className = 'pg-selected';

        var from = (pageNumber - 1) * itemsPerPage + 1;
        var to = from + itemsPerPage - 1;
        this.showRecords(from, to);
    }   

    this.prev = function() {
        if (this.currentPage > 1)
            this.showPage(this.currentPage - 1);
    }

    this.next = function() {
        if (this.currentPage < this.pages) {
            this.showPage(this.currentPage + 1);
        }
    }                        

    this.init = function() {
        var rows = document.getElementById(tableName).rows;
        var records = (rows.length - 1); 
        this.pages = Math.ceil(records / itemsPerPage);
        this.inited = true;
    }

    this.showPageNav = function(pageNumber) {
        if (! this.inited) {
            alert("not inited");
            return;
        }
        var element = document.getElementById(this.pagerName);
        var firstPage = parseInt(Math.max(pageNumber - this.maxPages / 2, 1));
        var lastPage = parseInt(firstPage + this.maxPages - 1);
        if (lastPage > this.pages) {
            lastPage = this.pages;
            firstPage = lastPage - this.maxPages;
            if (firstPage < 1) {
                firstPage = 1;
            }
        }
        var pager = this;
        element.innerHTML = '';
        element.appendChild(newSpan(' &#171 ', 'pg-ctrl', function () {
            pager.prev();
        }));
        for (var page = firstPage; page <= lastPage; page++) {
            element.appendChild(newSpan(page.toString(), 'pg-normal', changePage(pager, page)));
        }
        element.appendChild(newSpan(' &#187 ', 'pg-ctrl', function () {
            pager.next();
        }));
    }
}

function changePage (pager, page) {
    return function () {
        pager.showPage(page);
    };
}

function newSpan(text, className, onClick) {
    var span = document.createElement('span');
    span.id = 'pg' + text;
    span.innerHTML = text;
    span.className = className;
    span.onclick = onClick;
    return span;
}

function fillTable(id) {
    var table = document.getElementById(id);
    var html = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        html += '<tr><td>' + (i + 1) + '</td></tr>';
    }
    table.innerHTML = html;
}
```

```html
<table id="table"></table>
<div id="pager"></div>
```

Comment: Cara, no momento em que chego no 5º elemento, minha paginação não avança e não funciona mais com seu novo script

Comment: Nessa parte `var pagerHtml = getPagerHtml(pagerName, 1, this.pages);` você tem que atualizar o `1` com a variável que você utiliza para saber qual é a página atual.

Comment: kakamg, fiz a alteração mas ainda não obtive sucesso :/

Comment: editei a perguntando, adicionando mais informações do script

Comment: @AlexsanderCaproni Acho que agora está funcionando. Eu mudei um pouco a forma que é criado os spans da paginação.

Comment: Obrigado mesmo kakamg0! Salvou minha vida